# Alternatives for passive forms with semi-modals

Tags: passive-voice, semi-modals

It seems that passive forms of semi-modals verbs which ended in 'to' (like: used to, ought to, be able to, be going to, have (got) to) are not so common in everyday speech. Although some passive forms of these verbs may be more common than others (for example 'be going to'. I don't know). so what are the alternative passive forms or helping phrases (if exist) which could give a sense of passivization for these verbs

Comment: What do you think passive forms of these would look like? Examples, please. Oh, and these are not "semi-modals"; _need_ and _dare_ are the English semimodals. These are periphrastic modals, meaning they consist of more than one word. They're essentially idioms and don't inflect much.

Comment: for example "Languages were once taught at school by Mr Green." instead of "Languages used to be taught at this school by Mr Green. "

Comment: Both of those are passive.

Comment: @John Lawler. thanks. I edited the question